# Create an Index Based Class in c# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, oop

i've some classes and want to access their properties using index or something like

`ClassObject[0]` or better will be `ClassObject["PropName"]`

instead of this

`ClassObj.PropName.`

Thanks

Comment: please show some code... what are the types of your properties and please write why you want this way to access them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this, a *pseudocode*:

```
    public class MyClass
    {

        public object this[string PropertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                Type myType = typeof(MyClass);
                System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = myType.GetProperty(PropertyName);
                return pi.GetValue(this, null); //not indexed property!
            }
            set
            {
                Type myType = typeof(MyClass);
                System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = myType.GetProperty(PropertyName);
                pi.SetValue(this, value, null); //not indexed property!
            }
        }
    }
```

and after use it like

```
MyClass cl = new MyClass();
cl["MyClassProperty"] = "cool";
```

Note that this is not complete solution, as you need to "play" with BindingFlags during reflection access if you want to have non public properties/fields, static ones and so on.

Answer (score 9):

You need indexers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465(v=vs.71).aspx

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _innerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get { return _innerDictionary[key]; }
        set { _innerDictionary[key] = value; }
    }
}

// Usage
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c["Something"] = new object();
```

This is notepad coding, so take it with a pinch of salt, however the indexer syntax is correct.

If you want to use this so you can dynamically access properties, then your indexer could use Reflection to take the key name as a property name.

Alternatively, look into `dynamic` objects, specifically the `ExpandoObject`, which can be cast to an `IDictionary` in order to access members based on literal string names.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string this[int index] 
 {
    get 
    { ... }
    set
    { ... }
 }
```

This will give you an indexed property. You can set any parameter you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean here, but I'll say that you have to make `ClassObject` some sort of `IEnumirable` type, like `List<>` or `Dictionary<>` to use it the way to aim for here.