# Can we use c# indexer to index class properties?

Tags: c#

I want to index class properties like an array.

```
    Public class Foo
{
propery p1{get;set;}

propery p3{get;set;}
propery p3{get;set;}
.
.
.
.



}
```

I wan to index every propery like an array
FOO.p1=Value

Foo[0]=Value(index 0 refers to p1)

Comment: With reflection you can probably do this. Do you want to use reflection? Though I feel like this is an XY question. Why do you have those properties in the first place? Why not just use an array?

Comment: If you actually have numbered properties, it's usually a good sign that *you should have picked a collection type to start with*, not try to wrap them up with a collection-like wrapper.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an Index Based Class in c# .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090278/create-an-index-based-class-in-c-sharp-net)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the database, where there might have been a ready-made solution. But at least you can do it by reflection in this way:

```cs
using System.Reflection;


[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class IndexedPropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
    readonly int index;
    public IndexedPropertyAttribute(int index)
    {
        this.index = index;
    }
    public int Index
    {
        get { return index; }
    }
}

public abstract class WithIndexedProperties
{
    private Lazy<IReadOnlyDictionary<int, PropertyInfo>> properties;

    protected WithIndexedProperties()
    {
        properties = new Lazy<IReadOnlyDictionary<int, PropertyInfo>>(
            () => { 
                var linq = from prop in this.GetType().GetProperties()
                           let attr = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IndexedPropertyAttribute), true)
                           where attr.Length is 1
                           select (((IndexedPropertyAttribute)attr[0]).Index, prop);
                return linq.ToDictionary(p => p.Index, p => p.prop);
            });
    }

    public object? this[int propertyIndex]
    {
        get
        {
            return properties.Value[propertyIndex].GetValue(this);
        }
        set
        {
            properties.Value[propertyIndex].SetValue(this, value);
        }
    }
}
```

And there is an example:

```cs
Clss obj = new Clss();
obj[0] = "ABC";
obj[2] = 222;
obj[4] = 444;
// Here obj.A will be "ABC", obj.B will be 444 and obj.C will be 222.

public class Clss : WithIndexedProperties
{
    [IndexedProperty(0)]
    public string? A { get; init; }

    [IndexedProperty(4)]
    public int B { get; init; }

    [IndexedProperty(2)]
    public int C { get; init; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this. The code below is very generalized solution to your question and I might need some customization for yourself

```
using System.Reflection;

public class ReflectionBasedIndexedType
{

    public int A1 { get; set; } = 10;
    public int A2 { get; set; } = 20;
    public string SomeString => "Hello There";

    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _underlyingCollection;

    public object this[string name] => _underlyingCollection[name];

    public ReflectionBasedIndexedType()
    {
        _underlyingCollection = GetUnderlyingCollection();
    }

    private Dictionary<string, object> GetUnderlyingCollection()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> container = new();

        // get the properties defined in the class, I am filtering 
        // with constraint that, I want get only public and class level
        // Properties, which means I won't get any private/protected or 
        // static properties if there is defined such in the class
        // also where filters out indexer property, which we have defined 
        // inside this class, without this line, there will be exception
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(x => x.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0);

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            container.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(this)!);
        }

        return container;
    }

}
```

and than use case will be like this

```
ReflectionBasedIndexedType rbit = new();
var a1 = rbit[nameof(rbit.A1)];
var a2 = rbit[nameof(rbit.A2)];
var str = rbit[nameof(rbit.SomeString)];

Console.WriteLine(a1);
Console.WriteLine(a2);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

and output in the console will be this

```
10
20
Hello There
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have two ways at least.
The first one, is @Swapper mentioned, yo can use reflection. In this way, the class is normal and you have to write your hug code in where you want to use that class.
The second way is easier but a little fuzy. You can use `dynamic` type. If you know how to use it, that's ok. Otherwise please let me know, then I will create a sample code for you.

Comment: I dont know,please. Let me explain why I needed such class.

Comment: @MohammedMirmostafa,Let me explain why I needed such class. I am creating a WPF app that displays database data. To access the database tables I create a class with each table structure and bind it with wpf control. While retriving a data from the table using Sqlcommand.ExecuteReaderFunction(), I use Class.p1=reader[0] or Class.p1=reader[columnname]. That means I have to create as many data access functions as my tables. If I can somehow acess Class properties with with index,I can minimize my data access functions to single function.

Comment: If I'm right, you want to bind each table to a property of a class. I think `indexer` is much more better that dynamic properties. You can have a list of tables, feed by a DataReader. Then loop through the list and retrieve data.

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment, if at all.  "[You] can use reflection" and "You can use `dynamic` type" are the absolute tiniest _hints_ you could have given and not even actionable information, let alone a proper answer.